# How to show a popup in folium map?

Tags: python, html, json, popup, folium

I am showing some Covid data on a folium map. I want to show in the popup in the map some updated (day by day) data from this URL for a JSON file:

https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath_eueea_daily_ei/json/

How can I show cases and deaths in popup for a specific date, or for the last reported date (basically) in that JSON file?

Here is my code:

```
import folium

# this code for generating a map

m = folium.Map(
    location=[56.462490 , 13.753191],
    width= 650,
    height=550,
    zoom_start=4.36,
    tiles='https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    attr='My Data Attribution'
)


# this code for countries borders and show country name in the tooltip 

folium.GeoJson(
    r'/Users/bader/Desktop/pandaTable/european-union-countries.geojson',
    name='geoJson',
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['name_sort'],
        aliases=['Name'],
        sticky=True,
        opacity=2.3,
        direction='right',
    ),
).add_to(m)

m.save('map.html')
```

For the other reported dates, can I show them based on a dropdown menu? Or could the user can select a specific date to show the data on the map? Any ideas?